# Why won't my Timer control write out the contents of a session variable?

Tags: c#, timer

I have a long running process in a c# .net  web app. As the process runs, I am trying to update the page so the user knows what record they are on. I do this (or try to do this) using a timer control. The timer appears to work as expected, until I kick off the process. Then the timer never seems to run or is waiting until the process is completed and jut running once. Although I read timers run on their own thread, it seems as if they are running on the same thread.

Here is the markup for the timer...

```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>

     <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" >
     </asp:Timer>
```

And here is the function it calls, which should simply print out what was written to the session variable as the main process runs.

```
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string msg = string.Empty;

        if (Session["msg"] == null)
        {
            msg = "Processing....";
        }
        else
        {

            msg = Convert.ToString(Session["msg"]);
       }

        Literal1.Text = msg;
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the timer control inside the `ContentTemplate` for your `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: Yes. Started that way. No difference.

Comment: _"kick off the process"_ -- what _specifically_ do you mean by that? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. It's not clear from the code you posted why you should expect the client-side page to automatically update as the timer which is running on the server ticks.